# What if I use Redis ACL for client authentication on public?

Tags: authentication, redis, acl

First of all, I use Redis pubsub as a message broker to deliver real-time message between clients because it's low latency.

I have an idea to deploy Redis on a public endpoint but behind a gateway, and let the user connect to Redis directly. This will need to create ACL for each user and send them `username` and `password`. The ACL would be used to restrict the client's access to only those pubsub channels that were allowed.

**The Question is**

1. Is there a limit to how many ACLs Redis can have?
2. Does the number of ACL impact performance?

Comment: You have an application that connects to Redis and some users that connect to your application! so you need exactly one Redis user for your application. in situations where you have some users/apps that want to connect directly to Redis and you want to restrict their access, you will need ACL.

Comment: Thanks for answering, yep all user need to connect directly to Redis, I am questioning about would a lot of ACL (assume 100-1000 ACL) impact Redis performance.

Comment: Let's assume it is unbounded. now we should answer another question: "how many Concurrent Connected pub/sub Clients can Redis handle?"